# Why the angle between Two Vectors in a plane or in a space is not measured from head to tail?

Tags: vector-spaces, visualization

Let us assume two vector a and b such that they lie on the same plane.
Then if we want to measure the angle between a and b, For now, let us assume it to be θ Then why is the angle measured from the same initial point although the point of origin doesn't matter ,**why the same starting point?**Further, Why isn't it measured from head to tail as in the the end of vector a would be the origin or Starting point for vector b? What would be the intuitive way to understand it?

Comment: "*end of vector a would be starting point for vector b*"  What?  Are you perhaps confusing $b$ with $(a+b)$?

Comment: Short answer: none of this matters. You can put your vectors head to tail if you wish, it doesn't change the angle. When we do linear algebra, we don't think of vectors having a "head" or "tail", that is more a physics point of view (for instance when working with forces vectors).

Comment: @CaptainLama -- no head, no tail, but a direction. It makes a difference of $\pi$ if two verctors are parallel or antiparallel.